# Microsoft Outlook event reminders not showing on fullscreen apps

Tags: ms-office, notifications, fullscreen, reminders

I use a MacBook Pro and Microsoft Outlook for work, as well as an external monitor that I use as my primary (the built-in display is my secondary). I also frequently use applications in full-screen mode. However, when I am in a full screen app, Outlook's event notifications don't pop up. They play a sound, and they show when I switch views to the "main" desktop, but they do not show over the fullscreen apps.

How do I set Outlook so it can show notifications over top full-screen apps?

Here are my settings for Outlook and in Settings/Notifications:

[image]

[image]

[image]